# Unhandled Promise Rejections 17

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, unhandled-exception, mockgoose

i am writing test cases using mocha , mockgoose and chai. while running test cases i will get unhandle Promise Rejections 17 error.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 17): Mongod shutting down

[Unhandle Promise Rejection error 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWyfm.png)

```js
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var testData = require('./testData');
var apiUrl = require('./apiUrl');

chai.use(chaiHttp);


var Mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose,
      mongoose = new Mongoose,
      Mockgoose = require('mockgoose').Mockgoose,
      mockgoose = new Mockgoose(mongoose);

var server = require('../../../app');
var productFamily = require('../../../api/models/referenceData/productFamilyModel');
var productType = require('../../../api/models/referenceData/productTypeModel');
var product = require('../../../api/models/product/productModel');
var delivery = require('../../../api/models/delivery/deliveryModel');
var deliveryId;
var prod_common_cases = require("../common/product-common-cases");
var country_state_district_cases = require("../common/country-state-district-common-cases");
var delivery_common_cases=require("../common/delivery-common-cases");
describe('Delivery API', function () {
      before(function (done) {
            mockgoose.helper.reset().then(function () {
                  done();
            });
      });
      //Test1
      it("isMocked", function (done) {
            expect(mockgoose.helper.isMocked()).to.be.true;
            done();
      });

           it("should create productFamily", function (done) {
            prod_common_cases.create_prod_family(done);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

We need to set `timeout` as `it` async.  Simply put `this.timeout(222222)` in every test. i.e. in every `it` function.

```
 it("should create product Family ", function (done) {
     this.timeout(222222);     
     prod_common_cases.create_prod_family(done);
 });
```